# Work done by magnetic force is zero?

Tags: vectors

Could someone mathematically prove to me that the work done by the magnetic (Lorentz's) force is indeed zero. We are working with the Equation, F = Bqv where B is a constant vector, q is a charge and v is the velocity of the particle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this might be better asked at the physics SE, the simple answer is as follows:

$$W=\int \vec{F}\cdot \vec{ds} = q\int \left(\vec{B}\times \vec{v} \right)\cdot \vec{ds} = q\int \left(\vec{B}\times \vec{v} \right)\cdot \vec{v} dt=  \int 0 =0,
$$
since $\vec{v} = \frac{\vec{ds}}{{dt}}$ and $\vec{B}\times \vec{v}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{v}$, resulting in an integration over $0$.

Comment: I do not quite understand why Bxv is orthogonal to ds.

Comment: $v = ds/dt$ points in direction of $ds$, $B\times v$ is orthogonal to $v$. Or: $(B\times v)\cdot ds = \mbox{det}(B,v,ds) = 0$ because $v$ and $ds$ are linear dependent.

Comment: You could equivalently write $W=\int \vec{F}\cdot \vec{v}\,dt$.

Comment: @ David K, yeah you're right, I'll include that in my answer! Thanks